# Using Patternlab with TYPO3 Fluid

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, patternlab.io

I would like to use Patternlab to build Fluid-Templates for TYPO3.
I already found a standalone Version of the Fluid-Engine (didn't try it yet, though).

My question is, how do I implement the Fluid-Engine into Patternlab (instead of Mustache, for example)?

I reckon, that I need to download Patternlab for PHP and there the thin-version, so no other templating engine is already there?

PL would be awesome for TYPO3!

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Did you already try / achieve to make a fluid port of patternlab? :)

Comment: Not yet, but it seems there's a certain demand for it ;) - I hope I'll have time, soon...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing link is a fluid integration for Pattern Lab. This integration would do
the same job as [pattern-lab/patternengine-twig](https://github.com/pattern-lab/patternengine-php-twig) does for twig and 
[pattern-lab/patternengine-mustache](https://github.com/pattern-lab/patternengine-php-mustache) for mustache.

This integration doesn‘t exist yet AFAIK and needs to be written (could be named `patternengine-fluid`) and would then require 
[typo3fluid/fluid](https://github.com/TYPO3/Fluid). As I‘m not (yet) into Pattern Lab I can‘t tell you how complex this would get.
Guessing from e.g. patternengine-twig which ships around 680 SLOC (PHP) it‘s not a too complex task.

Once this part is available the rest is just following [Modifying the Thin Edition](https://github.com/pattern-lab/edition-php-thin#modifying-the-thin-edition-to-create-your-own-editions)

Would be nice to reflect it here if you make the effort to code (or let code) such a solution!

Regarding [fluid standalone](https://github.com/TYPO3/Fluid), it‘s this very package powering TYPO3 templates since version 8.0.

Answer (score 1):

There‘re two new projects around you might have a look at:

[Pattern Lab Fluid Edition](https://github.com/NamelessCoder/patternlab-fluid-edition) links Patternlab and Fluid

and 
[Pattern Lab Fluid Engine: TYPO3 CMS export](https://github.com/NamelessCoder/patternlab-fluid-typo3-export)
might ease exporting to a site package extension in TYPO3.

I haven‘t checked checked any of them - both sound promising, though…